# Run Jenkinsfile with hardcoded parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkinsfile which builds and deploys to different environments depending on a parameter
e.g.

```
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "integration", description: '', name: 'TARGET_ENV')
    }
```

When triggering the job, the user is currently asked, which environment to deploy to. I would like to setup one job-item per environment, which does not ask the user to enter the env.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This would then not be a parameter, but a regular variable, and you could use it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create one workflow (scripted) pipeline job for each environment und call your actual job with the set parameter:

Pipeline Script for Workflow Job 'deployEnvDev':

```
node {
   stage("Deploy Environment Dev") {
      build job: 'here/the/path/to/your/deploy/job',
      wait: true,
        parameters: [
            string(name: 'TARGET_ENV', value: 'dev' )
        ]
    }
}
```

Pipeline Script for Workflow Job 'deployEnvProd':

```
node {
   stage("Deploy Environment Prod") {
      build job: 'here/the/path/to/your/deploy/job',
      wait: true,
        parameters: [
            string(name: 'TARGET_ENV', value: 'prod' )
        ]
    }
}
```

The path 'here/the/path/to/your/deploy/job' to your deploy-job is shown on the detail page of the deploy-job:

[image]

This setup enables you to have different jobs to start the deployment for specific environments without asking the user to set the environment manually. The deployment itself is done in the same job as in the past. So you have a central job for modifications or maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Configure parameter in your pipeline UI.

[image]

Add to a script:

```
parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "integration", description: '', name: 'TARGET_ENV')
    }
```

And use in code:

```
echo "Parameter: ${TARGET_ENV}"
```